# Combination of dplyr::summarise + if didn't work

Tags: r, shiny

The code below is part of my `server` code.
I uploaded the dataset and aggregated the dataset by date.
However, if I use summary and `na.rm = TRUE`, `NA` will be replaced by 0 (if all records are `NA`), or if used without `na.rm = TRUE`, they will be summed to `NA` (if `NA` is present).
So I searched the code and modified it.
Surprisingly it worked in R, but not in R Shiny (data from many dates deleted).
Where did the problem arise?
What should I do?

```
tbl_sum <- reactive({
    data <- data ()
    table1<-data %>%
      mutate(date=as.Date(start_time),
             timestamp=lubridate::ymd_hms(start_time)) %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(heart_rate= if(all(is.na(hr))) NA_real_ else round(mean(hr, na.rm = TRUE),1),
                       oxygen= if(all(is.na(spo2))) NA_real_ else round(mean(spo2, na.rm = TRUE),1),
                       sleep_time = if(all(is.na(sleep_duration))) NA_real_ else round(sum(sleep_duration/ 60, na.rm = TRUE),0),
                       step_count = if(all(is.na(steps))) NA_real_ else sum(steps, na.rm = TRUE),
                       distances = if(all(is.na(distance))) NA_real_ else round(sum(distance/100, na.rm = TRUE), 1),
                       activetime = if(all(is.na(activity_duration))) NA_real_ else round(sum(activity_duration/60000, na.rm = TRUE), 1),
                       calories_burned = if(all(is.na(calories))) NA_real_ else round(sum(calories, na.rm = TRUE), 1),
                       time_difference = round(difftime(max(timestamp), min(timestamp), units = 'hours'), 0))
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See `ifelse()`.